# How can I get from Stansted Airport to central London cheap, at like 8 AM?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, london, stn

I need to reach central London (Piccadilly Circus for example) from Stansted airport at 8 AM.

Does anyone knows a cheap and easy way to make that circuit? Stansted -> Central London, Central London -> Stansted.

Comment: @Afonso, fares vary pretty wildly between all the London airports. I'd use skyscanner (website) to check fares for your particular day and route, you can set it to 'all london' airports to get whatever airport is cheapest.

Answer (score 5):

You can take the [train](https://www.stanstedexpress.com) or a coach. The main coach companies are [nationalexpress](https://www.nationalexpress.com/en/airports/stansted), [easybus](https://www.easybus.com/en/routes/london-stansted/) to get into London.   It is cheaper if your book your ticket a long time ahead, however you don't know how long it will take for you to get past passport control etc.

Then you need to take the tube or the bus, [Transport for London](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/) has a good website with a on-line planner.

The standard single train if you do not book is under £25 per person (a return is under £35), then you have the cost of the tube/bus.  The train runs 4 times a hour at peak times, see [thetrainline](https://www.thetrainline.com/) for timetables.

(It is also a LOT quicker from Stansted by train then it is from Heathrow by tube and Stansted being a smaller airport tends to have fewer delays.)

Comment: Comment: If you are booking the train, do NOT do so from thetrainline, since they charge a fee. Booking from the train operator directly (eg Cross Country, Virgin Trains) will not incur the fee.

Comment: @pnutsk may be worth the gamble, as it is only £2 if the bus is missed due to the flight getting in late.

Answer (score 2):

[Easybus](https://www.easybus.com/en/) is one good option.

If you book a long time (months) ahead, then one way ticket from Stansted to Baker Street will be £2 - the prices will go up with time though

Comment: Although at 8am it will take longer than usual as you hit the rush hour